# Table of contents not showing sites and pages in correct order

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, publishing-site

I have a publishing site with variations on. Here's my site structure.

```
Home  
    English  
        About  
            Page1  
            Page2  
            Page3  
        Services  
            Service1  
                Page1
                Page2
                Service1A  
                    Page1  
                    Page2  
                Service1B  
                    Page1
            Service2  
               Page1  
               Page2  
               Page3
```

My table of contents settings is:

Levels to show: 3
Show pages: Yes

But the actual table of contents page is displayed like following:

```
Home  
    Services  
        Service1  
            Service2
```

As you can see it is showing site Service2 under Service1 which is wrong. Plus it is also not showing site "About". And no pages are being shown either.

What's going on here? I just want to display sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, I am assuming you have a page used as the 'site map' / table of contents. 
Are you using the table of contents web part?

I have dealt with a very similar issue, this link will help you configure and set up the table of contents.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-the-table-of-contents-web-part-to-display-navigation-on-a-web-page-HA101794728.aspx

Comment: I suspect it is because the TOC web part only supports up to 3 levels but my site has 5 levels.